# E4 - how to remove caret from SourceViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I need to show something very similiar to source code, but it **shouldn't** be possible to modify it (but i still need funcionality as paint annotation etc.). The use case is more like - you click on some line and something will happen, some annotation will be shown etc.).

So i decided to try to use eclipse application platform, because its jface.text looks very good.

I am trying to use SourceViewer for my purposes. It could be configured to not be editable, but it is still drawing the caret if you click into it.

**QUESTION: How to disable painting of the caret?**

**EDIT: If you know something better than SourceViewer, which could fit to what i need, tell me please.**

```
SourceViewer sv = new SourceViewer(parent, new CompositeRuler(), 0);
sv.setEditable(false);
sv.configure(new SourceViewerConfiguration());
sv.addVerticalRulerColumn(new LineNumberRulerColumn());
sv.setDocument(new Document(""));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to set the caret to null with:

```
sv.getTextWidget().setCaret(null);
```